# Avoid container's overflow scrollbars with "enter from side" effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a one/single page scroll website. I have a couple of sections each one containing 2 columns and I'm trying to make them to enter from the left/right with a fade effect. I'm using CSS transforms and jquery to activate the effect only when the user scrolls and reachs its corresponding section. Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rv35g/
(Resize your window so it fits the container's width)

HTML:

```
<div class="container animation-init">
    <div class="left">Column 1</div>
    <div class="right">Column 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: green;
}
.container .left, .container .right{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
}
.container .left{
    background: red;
}
.container .right{
    background: blue;
}

.container.animation-init .left, .container.animation-init .right{
    opacity: 0;    
}
.container.animation-init .left{
    -webkit-transform: translate(-80px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(-80px, 0);
    transform: translate(-80px, 0);     
}
.container.animation-init .right{
    -webkit-transform: translate(80px, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(80px, 0);
    transform: translate(80px, 0);     
}

.container.animation-init.animation-ready .left, .container.animation-init.animation-ready .right{
    opacity: 1; 
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0); 
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.container').addClass('animation-ready');
});
```

The problem is that when my columns are on its initial position they generate horizontal scrollbars because they're going outside the container... Do you have any idea on how could I handle this? I can't use overflow: hidden; cause I'll be cutting part of the animation. I also tried to put overflow-x: hidden; to the html tag but since the effects only activate when you reach its corresponding section the overflow stills being a problem specially on mobile devices...

EDIT: The problem with overflow-x: hidden is that the extra space stills there, so when scrolling with your finger or mousewheel-click arrow function it's possible for you to end up in one of those blank spaces losing the center of the page. Also, in mobile devices, it takes this overflow as part of the general width, so If I have and element coming from -200px to the left, it'll show the container's width + the aditional 200. That's a problem, specially when it comes to the elements positioned at the bottom of the page, cause they're on their init position waiting for you to reach them to start the animation. In the example I posted the overflow disappears almost instantly cause the animation is being triggered automatically, but as I told you at the begining, I have multiple sections where the column's animation starts only if you reach their parent sections.

Comment: I don't see any scrollbars in Chrome...

Comment: I'm sorry, it was hard to reproduce it in the example... If you adjust your window to fit the container's width you'll see it.

Comment: I see now, I tried the `overflow-x:hidden` and it works in Chrome and FF. What issues did you have on mobile exactly?

Comment: Yeah, as @elclanrs says try an overflow: hidden or auto.

Comment: @elclanrs: the problem is that the extra space stills there, so when scrolling with your finger or mousewheel-click arrow function it's possible for you to end up in one of those blank spaces losing the center of the page. Also, in mobile devices, it takes this overflow as part of the general width, so If I have and element coming from -200px to the left, it'll show the container's width + the aditional 200. That's a problem, specially when it comes to the elements positioned at the bottom of the page, cause they're on their init position waiting for you to reach them to start the animation.

Comment: In the example I posted the overflow disappears almost instantly cause the animation is being triggered automatically, but as I told you at the begining, I have multiple sections where the column's animation starts only if you reach their parent sections.